# Prolog - how to check if a predicate succeeds more than once

Tags: prolog

I have a database of facts like this:

```
li(a,2).
li(b,3).
li(b,1).
li(c,2).
li(d,1).
li(d,1).
```

I need to write a predicate more(+Let) that succeeds if it exists more than one fact li(Let,_).

For example the queries more(b) and more(d) will succeed, but more(a) and more(c) will not. 
My idea was to check if li(Let,_) succeeds more than once, but I do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [`findall/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=findall/3):

```
findall(X, li(d,X), L), length(L,N), N>1.
```

Abstracting the `d` out and making a predicate is trivial. Right? :)

---

If you don't want to use any of the predicates like `findall`, you can change the representation of your knowledge - bring it down one level, so to speak:

```
my_knowledge(li, [a-2,b-3,b-1,c-2,d-1,d-1]).
```

and then you can use SWI Prolog's predicate [`select/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=select/3) to handle it:

```
select_knowledge(kn, key, R):-
  my_knowledge(kn,L),
  select_key(L,key,R).

select_key(L,K,R):-
  select(K-X,L,L1) -> R=[X|R1], select_key(L1,K,R1)
  ; R = [].
```

You can rewrite the last predicate as basic recursion over lists, and then tweak it to stop after getting first N results.

Comment: Your solution seems nice but I'm searching for a solution that uses only the predicates itself or basic predicates such as member, append, length, and obviously comparisons.

Comment: @markusian then you're out of luck. Counting how many times a predicate succeeds is not logic, it is above logic - i.e. it is not about proving something but about the workings of the mechanism to prove something. At the very least you have to use `assert`/`retract`, or `flag` etc. `findall` is just easier to use.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Will! So, if counting how many times a predicates succeeds is not logic, I should think about another way to do so.

Comment: @markusian and that's the way of using `flag`, or `assert`/`retract`, or `findall`, or `nb_setarg`. All legitimate parts of a programming language, Prolog. http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=nb_setarg%2f3 has sample `succeeds_n_times` predicate.

Comment: I just discovered that my problem was simpler than I thought because the predicate more should answer is if at least two facts li(Let,X), li(Let,Y), with X not equal to Y. I resolved it simply with 

     `more(L):- li(L,X), li(L,Y), X \= Y, !.`

Comment: @markusian if that's the case, then yes. `more(d)` will fail then.

Answer (score 5):

```
more_than_once(Goal) :-
   \+ \+ call_nth(Goal,2).
```

With `call_nth/2` as defined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364634/count-the-number-of-call-of-a-clause-prolog/11400256#11400256).

The big advantage of this solution compared to the other solutions proposed is that it will succeed rapidly even if there is a very large sequence of answers.  In fact, it will even succeed for an infinite sequence of answers:

```
?- more_than_once(repeat).
   true.
?- more_than_once(between(1,100000,_)).
   true.
```

(The implementation of `call_nth/2` uses some non-standard, low-level built-ins of SWI. It is possible to avoid that, but with even more headache.)

Answer (score 2):

SWI-Prolog has library([aggregate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.1%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/aggregate.html%27%29%29)).

```
:- [library(aggregate)].

more(Key) :- aggregate_all(count, li(Key, _), C), C > 1.
```

test:

```
?- more(b).
true.

?- more(a).
false.
```

It's not very easy to learn, but useful to handle such common tasks. If you have a very large code base, then findall (and aggregate as well, that uses findall inside) could be inefficient, building a list only to count its elements.

Then you could use a side effect based predicate: in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7520461/874024) related answer you'll find such utility. For max efficiency, see the comments, where is explained how to use nb_setval/nb_getval...

Comment: hmm, calling `findall(X, pred(X), [_,_|_])` may be read as showing the intent to cut down the number of actual calls to `pred` to no more than two ... but this could only be done at the level of implementation, right? Or may be it merits another name for the predicate altogether, like `findsome`. :) `findall` says "find *all*" after all.